# Playing ME3 co-op on a single PS3

Tags: mass-effect-3, ps3

Is it possible to play 2 player on one console on ps3 as both me and my friend want to play together or do we need to have to have 2 consoles and discs to play together? And if do we do can we do it via lan so its just us or do we have to do it via Internet with 4 players? Or is there anyway we can do it just with the one disc? (we have two consoles but only one of us has a disc) im asking in case we don't need to buy a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both console versions of the game lack support for local and system-to-system multiplayer.  You'll have to play via the internet.  You'll need 2 copies for this to work.

Co-optimus is the best source for this type of info, here's the [Playstation 3 page](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/2355/playstation-3/mass-effect-3.html) for ME3, and the [XBox 360 version.](http://www.co-optimus.com/game/2354/xbox-360/mass-effect-3.html)

Additionally, the difficulty doesn't really scale down with fewer players, so you might consider picking up some extra players over the internet if you want to play.  Otherwise it is likely to be quite hard.